# How to manually create a History List

Tags: 2010

I'm trying to create a sequential workflow but it says it needs a history list.

How do I go about manually creating such a list. I don't see any in the site templates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow History is automatically created in the site when a workflow is associated to a list (I think), but it is always hidden.

Answer (score 5):

Workflow uses list of TemplateType 140 - WorkflowHistoryList.

When adding workflow from user interface, Sharepoint suggests you to create this list automatically.

If U want to add it programatically, U can use feature receiver with following code:

---

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        var web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;

        _uniqueId = web.Lists.Add("WorkflowLog", string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.WorkflowHistory);
        _list = web.Lists.GetList(_uniqueId, false);
        _list.Hidden = true;
        _list.Update();

        _uniqueId = web.Lists.Add("WorkflowTasks", string.Empty, SPListTemplateType.Tasks);
        _list = web.Lists.GetList(_uniqueId, false);
        _list.Hidden = true;
        _list.Update();
    }
```