# SP 2010 Workflow History List is so large it stopped running workflows

Tags: 2010, workflow

I am cleaning up from my predecessor. Unfortunately, the workflow is inefficient and runs more times than necessary, creating a workflow history list of 450,000 items in a short time.

Before I can fix the workflow, I need to fix the Workflow History List, which we all know is not "cleaned" by the ridiculous WF cleanup timer in CA.

Should I just edit the workflows to point to a new workflow history list, and then delete the entire default list? I have already seen this: [How to delete a Workflow History list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74057/how-to-delete-a-workflow-history-list)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new history list but I recomend to delete the entries from current List and use it.

You can delete it with couple of ways:

- open the hidden list in datasheet view and then delete the items.
- Use the MSD's [Cleanup Workflow History](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cleanup-Workflow-History-cee6e75e) to clean the list, had very good success.

also check this one [How to manually create a History List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9290/how-to-manually-create-a-history-list)

Comment: I recompiled it for 3.5 framework. Don't forget to add the microsoft.sharepoint dll reference for SP 2010.